# I'd like to add dynamic drop down in nodejs via handlebar and also i would like to know how i call that function and export it to my stock.hbs file

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

**stock.js**

> const getdropdown = async(req, res) => {
> let sql = "select product_name from product";
> let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
> if (err) throw err;
> console.log('data :', recordset);
> res.render('stock', { dropdownVals: result.recordset });
> }); }

**stock.hbs**

```
  <div class="modal-body">
              <select>
    <% for (const i in dropdownVals) { %>
        <option value="<%= dropdownVals[i].ID %>"> <%= dropdownVals[i].Name %> </option>
    <% } %>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough information provided here. Also, I don't know what "export" means in this context.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.